# AttributeError: "str" object has no attribute "items" in recursive function for updating nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, attributeerror

I am having trouble with a program that is supposed to update dictionary keys from user-inputted values. I am consistently getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

Here is my code:

```
chIndexAbilDict  = {
    "Strength":0,"Dexterity":0,"Constitution":0,"Intelligence":0,"Wisdom":0,"Charisma":0
}
chIndexDict = {
    "abilityScores":chIndexAbilDict,"proficiencyScore": 0, "Character Level": 0
}

def characterSheet():
    global chIndexDict
    global chIndexAbilDict

    chIndexDictHash = copy.deepcopy(chIndexDict)
    chIndexAbilDictHash = copy.deepcopy(chIndexAbilDict)

    def statInput(stat, targetDict):
        statValue = pyip.inputInt(prompt="What is your " + str(stat) + "?\n")
        targetDict[stat] = statValue
        
    def dictUpdateValues(targetDict):
        for statKey, statValue in targetDict.items():
            if type(statValue) is dict:
                for k in dictUpdateValues(statKey):
                    statInput(k, chIndexAbilDictHash)
            else:    
                statInput(statKey, chIndexDictHash)
    
    dictUpdateValues(chIndexDictHash)
    chIndexAbilDict = chIndexAbilDictHash
    chIndexDict = chIndexDictHash

characterSheet()
```

I have been having issues with trying to iterate through and edit the values for the nested dictionary shown, as is currently the issue. What should I do to resolve this issue? Is there an easier way to go about this?

Comment: Typo: `dictUpdateValues(statKey)` should be `dictUpdateValues(statValue`)

Comment: `dictUpdateValues()` doesn't return anything. What do you expect to loop over when you do `for k in dictUpdateValues(statKey):`?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?

Comment: The goal for this code is to be able to iterate through a dictionary containing various DnD character stats, such as level and proficiency, which can also handle nested dictionaries for stuff like ability scores. I changed dictUpdateValues(statKey) to dictUpdateValues(statValue) which allowed me to iterate through the nested abilityScores dictionary, but unfortunately it returned with "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable." at the end.

Comment: As I said, `dictUpdateValues()` doesn't return anything. Why are you trying to loop over the result?

Comment: What should `k` be in that loop?

Comment: Ideally, k should be the keys in the nested dictionary, which i'm trying to update with the statInput function. I think I see the issue with using the function within itself without defining a return value, although I am unsure as to which value to return in this case. I apologize in advance for not knowing much of the terminology as I am relatively new to coding in general.

Comment: You shouldn't iterate over a returned dictionary. Each recursion level should iterate over the next level of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like in the function

```
def dictUpdateValues(targetDict):
    for statKey, statValue in targetDict.items():
        if type(statValue) is dict:
            for k in dictUpdateValues(statKey):
                statInput(k, chIndexAbilDictHash)
        else:    
            statInput(statKey, chIndexDictHash)
```

**statKey** is passed which is a string
and the function expects a dict and calls `targetDict.items()` while targetDict is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether a dictionary is getting passed when you call this function "dictUpdateValues(chIndexDictHash)"

Python is saying the "chIndexDictHash" is no longer a dictionary but rather a string (str). Python does not have ".items()" function on string (str). So check whether the deepcopy is doing exactly what it needs to do because you are saying "chIndexDictHash" is a deepcopy of "chIndexDict" and later passing "chIndexDictHash" as a "targetDict" parameter. I think there seems to be a problem when you deepcopy it. Just print and checkout whether something has changed.